# JqGrid grouping doesn't show last row data of the last page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I use date column to group data in jqGrid. But when I click the next page on pager the last row of the last page doesn't exist. Group header is shown but row data is missing. But when I fill data on a single page with rowNum property last row exists. Does anybody know what's the problem. Here are some properties I use:

```
gridview: true,
scroll: false,
treeGrid: false,
rownumbers: false,
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ['registrationDate'],
    groupDataSorted: true,
    groupOrder: 'desc',
    groupColumnShow: [true],
    plusicon: "ui-icon-plusthick",
    minusicon: "ui-icon-minusthick",
    groupText: ['<span><b>  {0}</b><span>']
},
rowNum: 25,
rowList: [5, 10, 15, 25, 30, 50],
loadonce: true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change this line on grid.grouping.js

`end = gg !== undefined ? grp.groups[i + 1].startRow : grp.groups[i].startRow + grp.groups[i].cnt;` is the line 389 in my version. The reason is that when the grouping pass to the last group the var "end" is set to the grdata.length but it would contain the rows per page which is not the value we need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Version 4.8.2 on the demo page on [www.gurrido.net](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/) this issue is fixed. The direct link to the Script is [jqGrid.min.js](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js). I also tried the download from the official page but without success.